# query multiple terms in multiple fields using elasticsearch

Tags: linux, elasticsearch

I want to search for multiple terms in 2 different fields (title, and description), the operator should be OR. Meaning that if any records contains any of these terms (heart, cancer) then that record should be returned.
Here is my code:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/INDEXED REPOSITORY/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-
Type: application/json' -d'{"query" : {"constant_score" : {"filter" : {"terms" 
: {"description","title" : ["heart","cancer"]}}}}}'
```

But, I get this error:

```
"error" : "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], 
all shards failed; shardFailures {[6hWIW7xlSbSqKi4dNg_1bg][geo_021017cde]
[0]: SearchParseException[[geo_021017cde][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse 
Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"query\" : {\"constant_score\" : 
{\"filter\" : {\"terms\" : {\"description\",\"title\" : 
[\"heart\",\"cancer\"]}}}}
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to resolve it:

```
{
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "terms": {
                                "description": [
                                    "heart",
                                    "cancer"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "terms": {
                                "title": [
                                    "heart",
                                    "cancer"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```